# i want to create a table with all records and column names from tableA to tableB in sql server

Tags: sql-server

> create table tableB as ( select * from tableA) 
>   --this works in oracle but not in sql server

Comment: the above given answers show duplicating records only!! I want to create a table along with the column names @Rob

Comment: What do you mean by duplicating records only? It inserts all the columns and rows into the table; which is exactly what you ask in your title.

Comment: does it create a new table because my tableB does not exist @rob

Comment: Yes, those answers will create `tableB` with the same columns, and insert all the data into it from `tableA`.

Answer (score 1):

Use into like this:

```
Select * into TableB from TableA.
```

Comment: I don't have a table b existing I want to create tableB by  extracting all the rows and column names @reds

Comment: Yes it will create TableB automatically. Including all the Data of TableA.